# How to implement load balancing in simple REST api?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, load-balancing

I have simple REST api written in CakePHP (php on apache). Basically it has just one endpoint, let's say `/api/something/?format=json`. Calling this endpoint doesn't read anything from DB, but internally it's fetching and parsing some external website and returns parsed data to the user in json format. The problem is that fetching and parsing data from external web page may last quite long and therefore I need some load balancing mechanizm which will distribute api calls among several servers.

I have never done any load balancing so I even don't know where to look for info - I am looking for the simplest solution.

Comment: Does the page update often, or could you cache the result? But if you're set on loadbalancing there is always: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

Comment: Every api call will parse different page so it cant be cached

Comment: HaProxy seems what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Is it a resource that has to be fetched live? Because you could cache the processed data for a certain amount of time.

If it has to be live, doing it in a distributed way is probably not going to solve your problem. (except when you're getting back a dataset that is very large)

Comment: Yes it has to be fetched live, in fact every api call will parse different page

Comment: I don't think that you could do this in a faster way. (assuming that you already use http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: What do u mean? If 100 peaople will call api, then one server has to download 100 pages - and when it will be distributed among 4 servers each server will has to download 25 pages...

Comment: Are you planning of doing the load balancing in your own code? Normally this is performed on a physical load balancing machine which is located in front of your webserver.

Comment: I dont know man - I have never done this and I have no idea how it is implemented/solved...

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)

Its pretty late but I guess This is what you need ! Just get the hardware to do all the good stuff !